# Postgresql - How to insert only if specific conditions are met

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have the following table:

```
create table foobar
(
    account_id  bigint    not null,
    timestamp   timestamp not null,
    balance_one numeric   not null,
    balance_two numeric   not null,

    primary key (timestamp, account_id),
);
```

Currently, I'm inserting thousands of records into this table at once using the following statement:

```
insert into foobar(account_id, timestamp, balance_one, balance_two)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), ETC...
on conflict DO NOTHING;
```

I want to add a constraint to the insert statement, stopping new records being inserted if `new.balance_one == old.balance_one AND new.balance_two == old.balance_two`
where `old` = the most recent (timestamp) record where account_id = new.account_id.

How do I do this? Insert performance is also a concern.

Comment: You are misunderstanding a key point about an `insert` statement:  all the rows are inserted "at the same time".  They are not inserted sequentially and checked.  Think in a set-based fashion.

Comment: I do understand that, I wish for my check to happen in parallel also.

Comment: You mean you want to avoid that a new record containing a combination of balances that already exists in the table is inserted?

Comment: Nearly, I want to avoid a new record containing the same combination of balances in the LAST record with the same `account_id`. LAST here meaning the record with the next highest `timestamp`

Comment: `insert (1, t, 2, 3), (1, t+2, 4, 5)` then `insert (1, t+1, 2, 3)`, is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should take a look at `ON INSERT` triggers. You could create a function :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_insert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE rec foobar;
BEGIN
  SELECT balance_one,balance_two FROM foobar INTO rec.balance_one,rec.balance_two
  WHERE account_id = NEW.account_id
  ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;    
  IF rec.balance_one = NEW.balance_one AND
     rec.balance_two = NEW.balance_two THEN
    RETURN OLD; -- this will silently ignore the insert for the current record
  ELSE
    RETURN NEW;
 END IF;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

... and attach it to your table

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_check_balances BEFORE INSERT ON foobar
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_insert();
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ea33104b8106d19af1005bdda21d9986)

**Note**: This approach will fail if you try to insert two records with the same `acount_id` in the same transaction, as all records in the transaction will get the same `timestamp` and your primary key will be violated.

Comment: There is also a race condition with concurrent inserts.

Comment: This is great! The way my system works there is a guarantee that each account_id will only occur once in each insert statement.

There is a problem with your solution though, if check_insert() throws, none of the other valid inserts take place. Is there a way to `skip` inserts where `check_insert` fails, and continue normally with the remaining?

Comment: @vddox yes, you can return `OLD`. Check my last edit :)

Comment: @JimJones Do you happen to know the performance implications of trigger functions?

Comment: @vddox no matter what approach you chose (subquery or trigger) there will always be a little overhead. It rather depends on the query itself. In your case: if the column `account_id` isn't indexed, you will see some significant delay as long as the table grows ;) cheers and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO foobar(account_id, timestamp, balance_one, balance_two)
WITH oldies AS (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (account_id)
        account_id, timestamp, balance_one, balance_two
   FROM foobar
   ORDER BY account_Id, timestamp DESC
)
SELECT n.*
FROM (VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?), ...)
  AS n(account_id, timestamp, balance_one, balance_two)
LEFT JOIN oldies o
ON n.account_id = o.account_id
WHERE o.account_id IS NULL OR NOT (
    n.balance_one = o.balance_one
    AND
    n.balance_two = o.balance_two
  )
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: I like this solution a lot - I will do some performance testing and then review the answer.

Comment: @vddox I added a fix that should take care of cases in which there is no old record. Leaving the testing to you.